# Hive - Select unique rows based on some columns

Tags: hadoop, group-by, hive, duplicates

I am trying to group rows that have the save value across two columns and have the result ranked/sorted based on a third column.

The result should contain all the other columns.

For the table:

```
with sample as (
 select 'A' as c1, 'B' as c2, '22:00' as c3, 'Da' as c4
 union all
select  'A' as c1, 'B' as c2, '23:00' as c3, 'Db' as c4
 union all
select  'A' as c1, 'B' as c2, '09:00' as c3, 'Dc' as c4 
  union all
select  'A' as c1, 'C' as c2, '22:00' as c3, 'Dd' as c4
  union all
select  'B' as c1, 'C' as c2, '09:00' as c3, 'De' as c4
)
```

Grouping or filtering by column *c1* and *c2* ranked by time on *c3*, the output would be:

```
row_number() over (partition by c1, c2 order by c3) as rnk

| c1, c2, c3,  c4, rnk|
----------------------- 
| A | B |09:00| Dc| 1 |
| A | B |22:00| Da| 2 |
| A | B |23:00| Db| 3 |
| A | C |22:00| Dd| 1 |
| B | C |09:00| De| 1 |
```

All the other columns like *c4, c5..* should be kept but don't have any effect on the group criteria or rank.

A believe a window function with partition on *c1* and *c2* and order by *c3* could work, but not sure if it's the best way in case of very large tables and the need to group by more columns.

The final output would be a UNIQUE row where rank is 1 (top). The columns should be exactly the same as the *sample* table (no rank).

`Select * from tableX where rnk = 1` would do the work but keep colum '**rnk**'.
I want to **avoid writing all the columns** in the select, **excluding** the rnk.

```
| c1, c2, c3,  c4 |
------------------- 
| A | B |09:00| Dc|
| A | C |22:00| Dd|
| B | C |09:00| De|
```

***Edited**, add final table

Comment: `rnk` is not a good choice as an alias for `row_number` since there is also a `rank` window function, with a different meaning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select  inline(array(rec))

from   (select  struct(*)   as rec

               ,row_number() over 
                (
                    partition by    c1,c2 
                    order by        c3
                ) as rn

        from    sample t
        ) t

where   rn = 1
;
```

---

```
+------+------+-------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3  | col4 |
+------+------+-------+------+
| A    | B    | 09:00 | Dc   |
| A    | C    | 22:00 | Dd   |
| B    | C    | 09:00 | De   |
+------+------+-------+------+
```

P.s. 
Please note that the columns names were aliased, due to the use of struct

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by c1, c2 order by c3) as rnk
from sample t;
```

The question seems to have changed since I answered it -- a rather rude thing to happen.  If you want the top ranked column, then use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by c1, c2 order by c3) as rnk
      from sample t
     ) t
where rnk = 1;
```

This returns one row for each combination of c1/c2 in the data.  If you want all rows in the event of ties, then use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edited the question. The first part you did I had it, my question is how to filter out duplicates. and not showing column `rnk` in the result. What you posted, does show the **rnk** col.

Comment: @RDs . . . Just select the columns that you do want in the outer query.  `SELECT *` is a handy way to answer a question, but may not be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: yes, I'd like to avoid the need to name all columns. **ALL**, **except* the `rnk`. `select *` is not what I need